# Is there a way to get the tens value from a number without condition statements?

Tags: c#, if-statement, numbers, range, refactoring

I have an application where I need the ones, tens and hundreds values from numbers between 10 and 120. I tested my theories out in a small program but I cant get tens to work without using **conditional statements**. This program generates numbers and tells you the ones, tens and hundreds values of the number with if statements. (I only want even numbers)

Is there any way to achieve these results without using an *If* or a *Switch* statement? (I couldn't figure out how to use the latter with 2 conditions)

```
using System;

namespace Digit_tests
{
    class Program
    {   
        static int digit; static int tens; static int ones; static int hundrds;
        public static void Main()
        {   
            hundrds = 0;

            Random rnd = new Random();
            digit = rnd.Next(10,121);

            if (digit % 2 != 0)
            {
                random();
            }
            else {}


            if (digit >= 10 && digit < 20)
            {
                tens = 1;
            }
            else if (digit >= 20 && digit < 30)
            {
                tens = 2;
            }
            else if (digit >= 30 && digit < 40)
            {
                tens = 3;
            }
            else if (digit >= 40 && digit < 50)
            {
                tens = 4;
            }
            else if (digit >= 50 && digit < 60)
            {
                tens = 5;
            }
            else if (digit >= 60 && digit < 70)
            {
                tens = 6;
            }
            else if (digit >= 70 && digit < 80)
            {
                tens = 7;
            }
            else if (digit >= 80 && digit < 90)
            {
                tens = 8;
            }
            else if (digit >= 90 && digit < 100)
            {
                tens = 9;
            }
            else if (digit >= 100 && digit < 110)
            {
                tens = 0;
                hundrds = 1;
            }
            else if (digit >= 110 && digit < 120)
            {
                tens = 1;
                hundrds = 1;
            }
            else if (digit >= 120)
            {
                tens = 2;
                hundrds = 1;
            }
            
            ones = digit - tens * 10;
            if (hundrds == 1)
            {
                ones = ones - 100;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(digit + "\n" + hundrds + "-" + tens + "-" + ones);
            Console.ReadKey();

            Main();
        }

        public static void random()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            digit = rnd.Next(10,121);
            Main();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the remainder operator:

```
int number = 345;
int tens = (number / 10) % 10;
```

So `345 / 10` == `34`, and `34 % 10` = `4`.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/KTN13597)

Answer (score 1):

```
int number = 12345;

int ones = number % 10;     // 5
number /= 10;               // 1234
int tens = number % 10;     // 4
number /= 10;               // 123
int hundreds = number % 10; // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the remainder operator (as per the other answer, which is probably better!), but honestly, for your use case I think a simple conversion to string is easier!

```
    int number = 421;  //The random number

    string numStr = number.ToString(); //Convert to string

    //Now we need to pad with zeros at the beginning if the number is < 100
    //A StringBuilder would be more efficient.

    int padd = 3 - numStr.Length;
    for(int i=0; i < padd; i++)
        numStr = "0" + numStr;
    
    //And output
    Console.WriteLine($"Hundreds {numStr[0]} : Tens {numStr[1]} : Ones {numStr[2]}");
```

This will only work for numbers up to 999, but you could expand it if you wanted to.

Comment: `numStr = numStr.PadLeft(3, '0');` is probably easier than the calculation and loop.

Comment: Looks pretty complicated, since im not that advanced in C# but it actually does look logical and kinda understood it, i could see it used in other applications too!